# If county court claim is issued to incorrect or old address, can a default judgment be entered against the respondent?

Tags: england-and-wales, civil-judgment

If an alleged debtor moves homes again and is then unreachable at his old address, or if the claimant simply has an incorrect address and serves the claim on this address, then the respondent can't be expected to respond. In this case can default judgments be entered and CCJ issued against the respondent and put onto the public register?

If so then what is to stop claimants from using made up addresses in bad faith in order to wreck adversaries' credit?

Answer (score 2):

### Because you get an unenforceable judgement

Default judgements are weak and can be set aside for all sorts of reasons. “I was never served” is one of those reasons.

Comment: Okay but then you can still end up with situations in which someone has default ccjs entered against them on the register and credit bureaus and has no idea about them and might find difficulty renting a place to live for example until they go through the effort to get the judgements thrown out. Is that more or less correct?